# Counting "sticks" (nodes with one child) in a binary search tree?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

So I am working with Binary Search Trees and one method I am having trouble with is a method called stickCt, which basically it will count the number of sticks in a tree and return the number. For it to be a stick it has to have a null and a non null child for it to be considered a stick, I have my code done and it complies but I keep getting 0 as my return value, I have no idea what is wrong I've tried moving stuff around but nothing seems to work some help would be greatly appreciated.By the way I am doing it recursively, here is the code:

```
// The number of nodes with exactly one non-null child
//driver

public int stickCt () {

    return stickCt(root);
}

private static int stickCt (IntNode T) {
    int num;

    //easiest case
    if (T == null) {
        num = 0;
    }
    //if the left child is null and the right child is not null
    else if (T.getLeft() == null && T.getRight() != null) {
        num = stickCt(T.getRight()) + 1;
    }
    //if right child is null and left side is not null
    else if (T.getRight() == null && T.getLeft() != null) {

        num = stickCt(T.getLeft()) + 1;
    }
    //recursive part
    else {
        num = stickCt(T.getLeft()) + stickCt(T.getRight());

    }
    return num;

}
```

Comment: The recursive logic you have here looks fine. What trees are you testing this out on?

Comment: While i'm glad that the answer below helped you, I'm concerned that you haven't actually identified the root cause of the problem you were running into. Does the new code work? If so, can you try to figure out why your original code didn't so that we can see what was wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you should return the sum of counting the sticks on every node, but instead you just return the current value of the sticks. You could rewrite the method in this way:

```
private static boolean onlyOneIsNull(IntNode node1, IntNode node2) {
    return (node1 != null && node2 == null)
           || (node1 == null && node2 != null);
}

private static int stickCt(IntNode T) {
    //easiest case
    if(T==null) {
        return 0;
    }
    //evaluating if I'm a stick
    int num = 0;
    if (onlyOneIsNull(T.getLeft(), T.getRight())) {
        num = 1;
    }
    //stickCt already takes care of null nodes, no need to add a null validation for nodes
    //need to return the number of sticks from left node and right node
    return stickCt(T.getLeft()) + stickCt(T.getRight()) + num;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works correctly - this counts the total number of nodes, not the total number of "sticks" (nodes with just one child.)

Comment: @templatetypedef oh ok, didn't get it right. Updating it.

Comment: So while I agree this is cleaner, what was wrong with the original code? It looks fine to me.

Comment: @vickes does this code really solves the problem? Because your code looks more verbose but should also work as templatetypedef posts.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I think OP's code misses the point that `num` is reset to 0 for every recursive call to `stickCt`. That's why it's incorrect.

Comment: @tonga if that were the case, in a tree with 2 nodes (root and left or right), it should return 1, but OP states it returns 0 (which is really odd) and by emulating OP's code it will return 1.

Comment: @tonga The count isn't being reset on each iteration - instead, a new variable `num` is created that's set to 0. The OP's code seems correct to me.

Comment: @templatetypedef: I think OP uses `return num;` where `num` is a local variable and its default value is 0 in Java. So it will not return the accumulative value after the stack returns (I think).

Comment: @tonga local variables doesn't have default value. If they are used but never initialized, the compiler throws an error.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza In Java, a local uninitialized int defaults to 0, isn't it? In C and C++, yes, it is true that local uninitialized int has junk value. A bit messed up for me :)

Comment: @tonga you can test it: `int b; System.out.println(b); //this raises a compiler error since b is not initialized`.

Comment: @tonga No, that's not correct. Java will report an error if you read an uninitialized variable. Plus, you can read through the code to see that the variable was indeed initialized in the OP's code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza OK, you're right. I just never used that way.